# How to use a JS date functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

In the process of learning how React JS works, I have run into statements such as this one:

```
var StartDate = new Date('2017-12-03T13:32:45.000Z');
```

1. I would like to know how I would tell that this is using the JavaScript Date object, instead of an object from somewhere else.
2. If it is a JavaScript date object are there any imports required for ReactJS to use it?

Comment: The Date object is a Javascript Built-in object, you don't need to import it.

Comment: Is that why React doesn't have its own date object?

Comment: Yes, you may refer to Nimee02 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code 'var StartDate = new Date('2017-12-03T13:32:45.000Z');' creates a new instance of the JavaScript Date object. It represents a specific point in time, in this case, December 3, 2017, at 13:32:45 UTC.

To check if the StartDate variable contains a JavaScript Date object, you can use the 'instanceof' operator to check its type.

```
if (StartDate instanceof Date) {
  console.log('StartDate is a JavaScript Date object.');
} else {
  console.log('StartDate is not a JavaScript Date object.');
}
```

As I know there are no specific imports required to use the JavaScript Date object within a React application. The Date object is a built-in JavaScript object, so you can directly use it in your React components without any additional imports or configurations.